# Qual seria uma boa tradução do inglês “feature”?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, termos-em-inglês

É comum falar das *features* de um novo produto, principalmente, senão exclusivamente, por pessoas que falam inglês, como [neste vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8BqNi9cj5M&t=200s).

As traduções apresentadas não são geralmente muito boas: “característica” é interessante, porém, uma *feature* é uma característica, mas uma característica não é necessariamente uma *feature*; idem com “aspecto”, “traço”, etc. Com essas traduções, a frase *it's a feature, not a bug* também não funcionaria.

Então pergunto: qual seria uma boa tradução da palavra inglesa *feature*?

Comment: Para software, it's a feature, not a bug. Bugs are found in computer programs. Feature quer dizer funcionalidade or função de um programa.

Comment: Só complementando: na engenharia de software o software é projetado para atender requisitos funcionais e não-funcionais. Os primeiros se referem ao que o software faz, isto é, o que oferece em termos de recursos ou funcionalidades/funções - eu costumo transitar entre esses três termos para traduzir _feature_ (um exemplo seria "gerar tal relatório"); e os últimos são mais "intrínsecos", como por exemplo ter que funcionar dentro de certos intervalos de desempenho, consumo de recursos, ausência de indisponibilidades e segurança (portanto mais relacionados ao "como" ou "quanto" que ao "o quê").

Comment: Contextualizando para quem não é do ramo, a frase é dita em tom de piada entre os programadores (mas parece que já foi aplicada de verdade, vide por exemplo [obsolescência programada](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsolesc%C3%AAncia_programada)) para justificar um bug indesejado como sendo na verdade um recurso intencional. Então eu pessoalmente talvez tentasse traduzir como _"não é um defeito, é um recurso pretendido!"_ ou _"é de propósito!"_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tradução do inglês não está errada. A característica pode ser facial, funcional, geográfica etc.

No caso do vídeo, seria uma tradução por **características funcionais** de um determinado objeto. Geralmente em pt-BR ouço o uso dessa palavra neste sentido.

Qualquer palavra aqui sugerida, pode talvez entrar na questão de que nem sempre será uma *feature*.

Recurso ou funcão:

> re·cur·so
> (latim recursus, -us)
> substantivo masculino
>
> 2. Meio; o que serve para alcançar um fim.

"recurso", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/recurso [consultado em 31-05-2021].

> fun·ção
> (latim functio, -onis, cumprimento, execução, trabalho, exercício)
> substantivo feminino
>
> 5. Uso especial para que algo é concebido. = FUNCIONALIDADE, UTILIDADE

"função", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o [consultado em 31-05-2021].

Alguns exemplos:

- [Loja de venda de equipamentos para PDV (Ponto de Venda)](https://www.automatizando.com.br/teclado-gertec-tec-12): característica
- [Buscador de preços em lojas online, exemplo de TV](https://www.zoom.com.br/tv/smart-tv-led-50-samsung-serie-8-4k-un50tu8000gxzd-3-hdmi): características, funções e recursos
- [Blog de tecnologia](https://www.techtudo.com.br/listas/2019/02/cinco-recursos-uteis-de-celulares-android-que-poucas-pessoas-usam.ghtml): recursos

Answer (score 2):

Eu recomendaria a tradução "Utilidades" nesse caso.

Embora também não seja uma tradução perfeita, pelo menos passa a mesma sensação de "possibilidades de uso de uma ferramenta".

Mas dependedo da frase e do contexto, outras traduções pode ser melhores. A própria palavra ferramenta pode ser uma boa opção em outros casos.